# Getting a list of items not only last list item gets rendered - React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I had a problem is that when I return some data from an API, add it to the state's array, I only get the last list item, even though it maps over more than 1 item.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    
    const fetchData = ()=> {
          DataService.getEnergyDataList()
          .then(response => {
            response.data.map(res=>{
             setItems([...items, res.Voltage])
          });   
        }
        )
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
        
        }
```

Comment: You're mapping over the response which contains just one item so it's only rendering one item. 
`const i = [...items, response.data.Voltage];
setItems(i);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `setItems` repeatedly (in the `map` callback), reusing the original items and then supplying just one more. That sets up a bunch of state updates, only the last of which is kept.

Instead, use the array that `map` creates:¹

```
const fetchData = () => {
    DataService.getEnergyDataList()
    .then(response => {
        setItems([...items, ...response.data.map(res => res.Voltage)]);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
};
```

---

¹ **Any** time you find yourself writing `map` without using the array that `map` creates, it's incorrect. (More on [my blog](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/).) Figure out whether you need that array and either modify the code to use the array `map` returns, or change the `map` to [some other looping mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are setting item for each element in `.map` callback. If you want to append the new response to items, you can use the callback approach of setState, something like:

```js
.then(response => 
     setItems(currentItems => [...currentItems, ...response.data.map(res=> res.votage))
    );
```

Comment: Yeah now it's working thank you man